# How to force users to reload Javascript files from someone else's server

Tags: javascript, caching

On my website, I use an external Javascript library. This library then loads several small dependencies. The main library has an expires date in 1969 (never caches), and the dependency libraries have expires dates in 6 months.

You might see where this is headed.

The library updated its code base. Since the main library doesn't cache and the dependencies do, they are now out of sync with each other for all my users.

So, bearing in mind that I have no control over the server for these files, is there a way I can force my users' browsers to reload the files? I can't do any of the typical cachebusting techniques (headers, version in filename, etc.).

I tried including the dependency files early with a version in the link, but that just resulted in the old and new files being loaded side by side, and the old version was still used.

Comment: There's nothing you can do about the dependencies loaded by the main library, assuming its code is in control of the URLs used.

Comment: Take a look to RequireJS (http://requirejs.org/), it is useful to load scripts and their dependencies on the right order.